# Данные формы не отправляются на E-mail. Сайт загружен на хост

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="b0.php" method="post" name="f1">

  <input class="area" type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Имя">
  <input id="#phone" class="area" type="text" name="phone1" placeholder="Телефон">
  <input class="sendform" type="submit" value="Отправить" name="sab">
  <p><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="chek">&nbsp;&nbsp;Я согласен с условиями обработки персональных данных</p>

</form>


$ofer="Заказ";

error_reporting( E_ERROR );   //Отключение предупреждений 
 // и нотайсов (warning и notice) на сайте

// создание переменных из полей формы       
if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {$name1 = $_POST['name1'];  

if ($name1 == '') {unset($name1);}}

if (isset($_POST['phone1']))    {$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];

if ($phone1 == '')  {unset($phone1);}}

if (isset($_POST['sab'])) {$sab = $_POST['sab'];        
if ($sab == '') {unset($sab);}}
//стирание треугольных скобок из полей формы
if (isset($nam1e) ) {
$name=stripslashes($name1);
$name=htmlspecialchars($name1);}

if (isset($phone1) ) {
$phone=stripslashes($phone1);
$phone=htmlspecialchars($phone1);
}

// адрес почты куда придет письмо
$address="maxburtsev.work@gmail.com";
// текст письма 
$note_text="Тема : $ofer \r\nИмя : $name1 \r\n Телефон : 
$phone1 \r\n";

if (isset($name1)  &&  isset ($sab) ) {
mail($address,$ofer,$note_text,"Content-type:text/plain; 
windows-1251");
// сообщение после отправки формы
echo "<p style='color:#009900;'>Уважаемый(ая) <b>$name1</b> 
Ваше письмо отправленно успешно. <br> Спасибо. <br>Вам 
скоро перезвонят <b> $phone1</b>.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Чуть чуть бы подробней нежели просто "не отправляются".. Может ошибки какие выдает? или например письмо уходит но данных нет....

Comment: Никаких ошибок, просто сообщение не приходит на мыло. сайт находится на хосте

Comment: `error_reporting( E_ERROR );   //Отключение предупреждений` Как бы логично что ошибок вы не видите =) А теперь еще раз и сначала, и в текст вопроса(кнопка редактировать): **Что выводит вам скрипт?** Это первое, второе - у вас VPS\VDS или именно хостинг для сайтов?

Comment: Возможно почтовый сервис блокирует отправителя. Недавно сталкивался с этим. В настройках почтового сервиса попробуй посмотри фильтры.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков закоментировал `error_reporting( E_ERROR ); //Отключение предупреждений` ошибок все равно нет никаких. Скрипт переводит на страницу, которая потверждает, что все отправлено, но сообщение не приходит

Comment: Вы либо специально игнорируете вопросы в комментариях или моя не понимать с какой целью, у вас хостинг **для сайтов** или **VPS\VDS**? **и то и другое - хостинг** только в случае вашей проблемы решение для них разное.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков обычнй хостинг без VPS\VDS. Вот его адресс http://ca54485.tmweb.ru/

Comment: Во певых проверьте папку спам. Во вторых укажите отправителя письма(у вас этого не сделано). В третьих проверьте письма не доходят только до gmail или до например yandex\mail тоже? Если письма не доходят только до google обращайтесь в тех поддержку хостинга и\или гугла

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в спам тоже нмчего не приходит

Comment: Ответы на остальные вопросы надо вытягивать с помощью [инструмента?](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Pincers.jpg)

Comment: Что возвращает функция `mail(...);` ?